# Error - "Too many intermediates for path length constraint" when register new identity

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In hyperledger fabric-ca, I create chain of CAs like:

> Root CA - Intermediate CA 1 - Intermediate CA 2 - Intermediate CA 3

With these CAs, in "signing" part of fabric-ca-config.yaml file I set "maxpathlen:5", and in "csr" part I set "pathlength:5"
It's mean my chain is valid for at least 4 Intermediate CA and I can register new identity in Intermediate CA 3.

In fact, I can enroll admin of Intermediate CA 3, however, when I register new identity, I have this error:

> /register 401 26 "Untrusted certificate: Failed to verify certificate: x509: too many intermediates for path length constraint"

What wrong I have done, and how to config this value
My config file

```
# Version of config file
version: 1.1.0

# Server's listening port (default: 7054)
port: 7054

# Enables debug logging (default: false)
debug: false

# Size limit of an acceptable CRL in bytes (default: 512000)
crlsizelimit: 512000

tls:
  # Enable TLS (default: false)
  enabled: false
  # TLS for the server's listening port
  certfile:
  keyfile:
  clientauth:
    type: noclientcert
    certfiles:

ca:
  # Name of this CA
  name:
  # Key file (is only used to import a private key into BCCSP)
  keyfile:
  # Certificate file (default: ca-cert.pem)
  certfile:
  # Chain file
  chainfile:

crl:
  # Specifies expiration for the generated CRL. The number of hours
  # specified by this property is added to the UTC time, the resulting time
  # is used to set the 'Next Update' date of the CRL.
  expiry: 24h

registry:
  # Maximum number of times a password/secret can be reused for enrollment
  # (default: -1, which means there is no limit)
  maxenrollments: -1

  # Contains identity information which is used when LDAP is disabled
  identities:
     - name: Admin
       pass: adminpw
       type: client
       affiliation: 
       attrs:
          hf.Registrar.Roles: "*"
          hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "*"
          hf.Revoker: true
          hf.IntermediateCA: true
          hf.GenCRL: true
          hf.Registrar.Attributes: "*"
          hf.AffiliationMgr: true

affiliations:
   org1:
      - department1
      - department2
   org2:
      - department1

signing:
    default:
      usage:
        - digital signature
      expiry: 8760h
    profiles:
      ca:
         usage:
           - cert sign
           - crl sign
         expiry: 43800h
         caconstraint:
           isca: true
           maxpathlen: 5
      tls:
         usage:
            - signing
            - key encipherment
            - server auth
            - client auth
            - key agreement
         expiry: 8760h

csr:
   cn: fabric-ca-server
   names:
      - C: US
        ST: "California"
        L:
        O: Hyperledger
        OU: Fabric
   hosts:
     - ca
     - localhost
   ca:
      expiry: 131400h
      pathlength: 5
```

Comment: So are you trying to enroll "Intermediate CA 3"?  It would be helpful if could post the commands and/or code that you are running.  I suspect that you are trying to actually enroll "Intermediate CA 3" using the fabric-ca-client?  In that case, you need to make sure that you pass in the `--enrollment.profile "ca"` flag

Comment: I can enroll Admin user of Intermediate CA 3, but after that I can't register new identity in "Intermediate CA 3", it always throw above error

Comment: can you post your `fabric-ca-config.yaml` file or at least the ca profiles section?

Comment: I update config file in my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause is simple because when initialize network, I don't create cert/key by myself and config it so that Fabric-CA use itself key/cert which config default set maxpathlen=1.
If I create cert/key by myself and in cert config pathlength > 3 then my network will be ok.